# jQuery image resize

Tags: jquery

I need to do something like when a span is hovered over, the image grows larger (so from like 75% to 100% size). I tried something like

```
$("img#myselector").css("width", "75%");
$("img#myselector").css("max-width", "75%");
$("img#myselector").css("height", auto");
//mouse enters the span
$("img#myselector").css("width", "100%");
$("img#myselector").css("max-width", "100%");
//mouse leaves the span
$("img#myselector").css("width", "75%");
$("img#myselector").css("max-width", "75%");
```

but this blew up the image to 200% its normal size, instead of shrinking/increasing the size.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say I got the problem exactly but I hope you are aware of that width:75% is calculated with respect to parent element's width.

Comment: Try it with hard coded values:  100px to 200px back to 100px to see if it's a percentage problem.  The parent container may be expanding to fit the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HasanAyan said, you are resizing the image with respect to the container of the image. 
If the image was in the `body` of the site, you would be trying to use all the width of the page with `width:100%`.

You should specify the pixels.

For it, you can make use of `height()` and `width()` functions of jQuery and get the original size to operate with it later:

```
var originalWidth = $('#myselector').width();
```

Here you have an example working:
http://jsfiddle.net/bX3GU/